# multiple spring-boot war into ear with skinny wars

Tags: spring-boot, ear, skinny-war

Can someone please point me to an step by step guide on how to package 2 spring-boot war applications into an ear with skinny wars?

I have both spring-boot applications deployed and working separately on a jboss-eap-6.2 server, but when I try to package them into an ear the result doesn't deploy.

maven ear plugin configuration? pom.xml configuration?

Comment: As far as I can see, there are some fundamental class loader issues that make this hard to get working. I have an example project with work arounds here: https://github.com/purple52/spring-boot-ear-skinny-war